# Why does std::(multi)set provide non const iterator methods

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, set, stdset

Why do the sets (`std::set` and `std::multiset`) in the C++ standard library provide non `const_iterator` methods ([`set::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/begin) and [`multiset::begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/begin))?

Access to the keys through iterators is always `const`. It does not matter if the set itself is const or not. **Why introduce those extra overloads?**

Comment: @TemaniAfif How is this a duplicate of that question?

Comment: For completeness and generality, to comply with [Container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) concept.

Comment: @yurikilochek how is it not general enough to only provide const methods for things that return const references to contained values?  Can you give an example of general code that will fail if those non const iterators methods are not present?  The only thing I can think of is something that has partial specializations that detect the presence of a non const begin() and end() method.

Comment: @yurikilochek the container concept does not mention that a class must have non const qualified begin and end methods, it only says that a container must have them.  Which the sets do.  cbegin() and cend() are a different story and not entirely relevant here

Comment: Before C++11, modifying operations which accepted iterators from the set (such as `erase` and the hint version of `insert`) required non-const iterators. So that could be one reason.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think that can be solved by keeping the alias `const_iterator` right?

Comment: @Curious, per [container.requirements.general/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements) `a.begin()` must return `const_iterator` for const `a`, and `iterator` otherwise.

Comment: @Curious: It could, yes. I suspect they simply hadn't thought of that at the time of the original standard, just like they hadn't thought of the fact that it shouldn't be necessary to pass non-const iterators, even though the function is modifying the set (because the set itself is non-const).

Comment: @yurikilochek that just says `iterator; const_­iterator for constant a`, so that will not matter if `iterator` and `const_iterator` are the same type.  C++ does not have strong aliases

Comment: @Curious if they were the same type, user code wouldn't be able to overload on them.

Comment: @yurikilochek and user code shouldn't overload on them right?  The standard never specifies if those iterator classes are actually distinct types or whether they are aliased to the same underlying implementation.  In fact libstdc++ does exactly this https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h#L138-L139

Comment: I believe but am not 100% sure that early versions of `set` would allow you to modify the object at an iterator. Of course modifying the object in a way that reordered it would result in undefined behavior, but there are many cases where part of the object is a key and the rest could be safely modified. I honestly don't know why that's not allowed.

Comment: [`std::set::erase`](http://eel.is/c++draft/set#overview-2) is overloaded on them. Can we apply as-is rule here?

Comment: @yurikilochek not sure why the standard specifies those as two distinct functions.  libstdc++ again only has one of them https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h#L627 I think it might be there in the standard as a guideline for implementations in which they are two distinct types.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in [[member.functions]](http://eel.is/c++draft/member.functions), it's expressed that:

> For a non-virtual member function described in the C++ standard library, an implementation may declare a different set of member function signatures, provided that any call to the member function that would select an overload from the set of declarations described in this document behaves as if that overload were selected.

The standard defines behavior for each container in [[container.requirements.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements) which require that:

- `a.begin()` yields an `iterator` (or `const_iterator` for constant `a`)
- `a.end()` yields an `iterator` (or `const_iterator` for constant `a`)
- ...

The requirement for the implementations are that those types (`C::iterator` and `C::const_iterator`) exist and that those functions yield those types. The requirement is **not** specifically that those four overloads must exist (nor that the two iterator types must be different). The requirement is just the behavior.

The following would be a perfectly conforming implementation for `set`:

```
template <class Key, class Compare = std::less<Key>, class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>>
class set {
public:
    struct iterator { ... };
    using const_iterator = iterator;

    iterator begin() const { ... };
    iterator end() const { ... };

    // other stuff
};
```

With this implementation, all the requirements are satisfied. So it's sufficient. Indeed, this is how libstdc++ implements it - the two iterators are the [same type](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h#L138-L139) and there is just one [`begin()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h#L334-L336) and just one [`end()`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_set.h#L343-L345).

> Why introduce those extra overloads?

There aren't extra overloads. Or at least, there don't have to be. It's up to to the implementer.

Answer (score -1):

While I can't say for certain, consistency (see comments by @yurikilochek) seems reasonable to me. "Can you give an example of general code that will fail if those non const iterators methods are not present?" The following code does not compile with libstdc++ (but does compile under Visual Studio) because set does not have the non-const methods. I acknowledge this is not code someone would write in the course of a day that is going well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

template <class C> //C is some container
void f(C& c)
{
    typedef typename C::iterator iter;
    typedef iter (C::*fn)(); // note non-const method

    fn begin = &C::begin; // will fail with set if begin() is const only
    fn end = &C::end;

    for (iter i = (c.*begin)(), e = (c.*end)(); i != e; ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int
main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::set<int> s;

    f(v);
    f(s);

    return 0;
}
```