# Why do associative containers have an erase overload with non-const iterator argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, erase

C++11 changed [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) to take a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`. The same thing applies to [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/erase) and [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase), while `std::forward_list` came in C++11 with [`erase_after`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list/erase_after), which also takes a `const_iterator`.

In contrast, [`std::set::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) kept its `iterator` overload and C++11 simply added the `const_iterator` one. The same thing applies to all associative containers: [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase), [`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/erase), and [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/erase) all kept the pre-C++11 `iterator` overload while [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/erase), [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase), [`std::unordered_multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset/erase), and [`std::unordered_multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/erase) all were introduced with both `iterator` and `const_iterator` overloads.

In fact, for all four set classes, [`iterator` and `const_iterator` may very well be the same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457311/why-does-stdmultiset-provide-non-const-iterator-methods).

So why the discrepancy? In addition to the inconsistency with the non-associative containers, there is also an inconsistency with the range erase overloads, which were all changed with C++11 to take a pair of `const_iterator`s instead of a pair of `iterator`s. Since an `iterator` must be convertible to a `const_iterator`, there is no need to have all four possible combinations of parameters for the range erase. Similarly, there is no need to have "all two combinations" for the single-value erase, so why keep the `iterator` overload?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Originally in C++11 the old `iterator` overload was replaced by the `const_iterator` one for all of these containers.

However, the associative containers have always had additional `erase` overloads that take a key type as parameter. Sequence containers like `std::vector` and others do not have additional overloads of that kind.

So, if you add the `const_iterator` overload and remove the `iterator` overload, and `iterator` and `const_iterator` are not the same type, then there is a chance that overload resolution becomes ambiguous where it wasn't before C++11, e.g. if the key type has a constructor from `iterator`.

Therefore the resolution of [LWG issue 2059](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2059) added the old `iterator` overloads back as a defect report. For the unordered associative containers added with C++11 these were probably added in the same way so that there isn't an unnecessary interface difference between the two kinds of containers.

Comment: So if `std::vector::erase` had an overload taking a value (erasing everything comparing equal, kind of like `std::multiset::erase`), then it would also need an overload taking an `iterator`, like it had prior to C++11?

Comment: @Nelfeal Yes, "need" is strong, but it would be preferable since it disambiguates the call in a special case that otherwise would need an explicit conversion to `const_iterator`.